# publishing with adobe air in flash professional cs6

Tags: ios, air, adobe, publishing

I am working at publishing my app as an iOS app with Adobe Flash Professional CS6.

The Error that I am receiving is:

An attribute or element contains an invalid value in the application descriptor file.
  (application.iPhone.InfoAdditions)

my file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.2">
  <id>com.itsgamingplus.itsgood</id>
  <filename>ItsGoodIpod</filename>
  <description/>
  <!-- To localize the description, use the following format for the description     element.<description><text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text><text     xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App      description goes here</text></description>-->
  <name>ItsGoodIpod</name>
   <!-- To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.<name><text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text></name>-->
  <copyright/>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>ItsGoodIpod.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
   </initialWindow>
  <icon>
    <image512x512>icon1.png</image512x512>
    <image29x29>icon2.png</image29x29>
    <image57x57>icon3.png</image57x57>
  </icon>
    <iPhone>
        <InfoAdditions>
       <![CDATA[<key>UIDeviceFamily</key><Array><string>1</string></Array>]]>
    </InfoAdditions>
     <requestedDisplayResolution>standard</requestedDisplayResolution>
   </iPhone>
   <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
  <versionNumber>1.4</versionNumber>
  <supportedLanguages>en</supportedLanguages>
</application>
```

I have gone as far as removing the xml file and making flash professional generate a new file but with the same error.

any suggestions are helpful

Comment: UIDeviceFamily is a number, not a string.  I don't know if that makes a difference here.

Comment: From everything that I have seen it is supposed to be noted as string.   One thing I have noticed while I continue to search is that the <Array></Array> in others files are in lowercase (<array></array>)  Could this be my problem?  And if so how do I stop flash professional CS6 from adding it while compiling.

Comment: http://powercoder23.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/error-105-application-iphone-infoadditions-contains-an-invalid-value/ Please check this link this might be helpfull Thanks
Dhiraj

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Array node is case-sensitive. It has to be lower case or you'll get the "invalid value" error message. This is correct:

```
<![CDATA[<key>UIDeviceFamily</key><array><string>1</string></array>]]>
```